# Limit task if ALL hosts are targetting

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to limit a task/role to multiple host with the condition that all these hosts are reachable?

For example the following

```yaml
- hosts: backend:cluster
  roles:
    - "install_keys"
```

We have large inventory and to avoid fetching every server every time, we use a lot the `--limit` option of `ansible-playbook`. So when I use `ansible-playbook ... --limit "backend"`, I don't want to execute the role in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Use *group_names*. For example, given the inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
[backend]
host1
[cluster]
host2
```

the play

```yaml
- hosts: backend:cluster
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_groups: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                       map('extract', hostvars, 'group_names')|
                       flatten|unique}}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: my_groups
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml

  my_groups:
  - backend
  - cluster
```

When you limit the inventory to *backend* you get

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --limit backend

  my_groups:
  - backend
```

Then you can include a role if the inventory is not limited to a specific group, e.g.

```yaml
    - include_role: install_keys
      when: my_groups|difference(['backend'])|length > 0
```

---

As a side note: If you have a large inventory you might want to use a dictionary of the groups and related roles, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: backend:cluster
  vars:
    my_roles:
      backend: [roleA, roleB]
      cluster: [roleC]
      backend-cluster: [roleD, roleE]
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_groups: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                       map('extract', hostvars, 'group_names')|
                       flatten|unique}}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        msg: "include role: {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_roles[my_groups|join('-')] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --limit backend

ok: [host1] => (item=roleA) => 
  msg: 'include role: roleA'
ok: [host1] => (item=roleB) => 
  msg: 'include role: roleB'
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml

ok: [host1] => (item=roleD) => 
  msg: 'include role: roleD'
ok: [host2] => (item=roleD) => 
  msg: 'include role: roleD'
ok: [host1] => (item=roleE) => 
  msg: 'include role: roleE'
ok: [host2] => (item=roleE) => 
  msg: 'include role: roleE'
```

Comment: Nice thanks it works pretty well. I don't understand what's |difference means here.

Comment: See [Selecting from sets or lists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory).

Comment: That's a lot of extra work to get at what is already directly available in group_names...

Comment: Just the opposite. The question says ``"large inventory ... we use a lot the --limit option"``. I'd argue that putting the roles/groups logic into a dictionary and using the single loop is less work compared to creating conditions for each *include_role* task.

Answer (score 0):

If you never want the role included on the backend group but always on other groups, call include_role explicitly instead of using `roles:`

```yaml
- name: run this role everywhere but backend
  include_role:
    name: install-keys
  when: "'backend' not in group_names"
```